# How to kill a Python process within an SSH session

Tags: bash, ssh, process, kill, nohup

This question involves running a bash script, say `helloworld.sh`, which executes an MPI `mpirun` command which in turn runs a Python program, say `helloworld.py`, using [mpi4py](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). The bash command is used in an SSH terminal from one "master" node which will initiate the program `helloworld.py` in multiple "worker" nodes. To make the command robust to SSH connection drops I use `nohup` and redirect the output to a file. The command is

```
nohup bash helloworld.sh > log.txt &
```

After that, a message like this is printed

```
[1] 23802
nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
```

I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and the session disconnects while the program runs normally.  The bash script `helloworld.sh` is something like

```
mpirun -n 25 --hostfile myhostfile.txt python helloworld.py
```

which will run `helloworld.py` on the "master" and some "worker" nodes (25 nodes in total).

My problem is that sometimes I want to kill this program. I re-login and execute:

```
pkill -9 23802
```

Nothing seems to happen, the program keeps running in all nodes. Then, I run `top -c` and get its PID which is different (why?) from what `nohup bash` printed, say 23844. I tried running

```
pkill -9 23844
```

Still no effect. Note that I need a way to kill only this process, not all Python programs that may be running, i.e., `pkill -9 python` is not suitable for me.

Comment: `pkill` is used with *names*, not PIDs, and `kill` is used with PIDs.

Comment: Oh I see, but why is the PID printed at execution (23802) different than the one I see in `top` (23844) and which one should I use?

Comment: The PID is for the shell running the script itself, which as you said, uses `mpirun` to start another process, for which you see a different PID in `top`. Depends on what you want to kill.

Comment: I'll add to this problem, I would suggest using "supervisord" for python scripts/clients/servers, it would be a lot easier to manage. Or you can use systemd to create "daemon-like" process, running such things in background or similar is okay for temporary usage, but AFAIK you are using at full scale.